# .net mvc 3 foreach in foreach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

OK. I have 3 classes. Category, SubCategory and SubSubcategory.

I want to (using razor) display them. However it is not likely my syntax:

I think:

```
  <ul>
  @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <li>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })

            <ul>
            @foreach (var sc in item.SubCategories)
            {
                @Html.Display(sc.Name)

                foreach (var ssc in sc.SubSubCategories)
                 {
                     @Html.Display(ssc.Name)
                 }
            }
            </ul>
    </li>
  }
  </ul>
```

However it is not populating SubCategory and SubSubCategory. I've tried from the controller end to give it: db.Category.ToList(); (however this only gives me the first level.. SubCategory and SubSubCategory are ignored.

I tried with db.Category.Include("SubCategory").ToList(); but it did not like this. How do i populate all 3 levels of this?

Comment: Your view is fine.  You need to make sure the collections aren't empty.  Please show your controller.

Comment: thanks for fixing the syntex @Andrew Whitaker

Comment: My controller only contains: 
        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            var model = db.Category.ToList();
            return View(model);
        }

Because I'm unsure how to add my two "joinable" tables"

Comment: private HelpMeContext db = new HelpMeContext(); <-- my db is my context based on CodeFirst and EF4.1

Comment: I guess that problem really is that i need to know how to populate the SubCategory list which is contained within each Category.

Comment: @NielsRobinAagaard - don't add code in comments, edit your question to include the info so it's all in the original post.

Comment: @NielsRobinAagaard - Refrain from saying things like "That didn't work, or it didn't like it" without describing exactly what that means, such as a specific error or other description of the problem.  We can't help you if you are vague.

Comment: Is SubCategory actually a collection in your Category class?  You need to also post your three entities.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with EF, but I know in LINQ-to-SQL, you could use DataLoadOptions to include other joined data:

```
HelpMeContext db = new HelpMeContext();

DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
options.LoadWith<Category>(c => c.SubCategories);
options.LoadWith<SubCategory>(sc => sc.SubSubCategories);
db.LoadOptions = options;

// now this should load subcategories and sub-subcategories with it.
var model = db.Category.ToList();
```

You could also try selecting all of the data into an anonymous type, but it's a little messier to read and to work with as well:

```
var model = db.Category
    .Select(c =>
        new { Category = c, SubCategories = c.SubCategories.Select(sc =>
            new { SubCategory = sc, SubSubCategories = sc.SubSubCategories }
        )}
    ).ToList();
```

From which you could say:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    //item.Category.Name
    @foreach (var sc in item.SubCategories) {
        //sc.SubCategory.Name
        @foreach (var ssc in sc.SubSubCategories) [
            /ssc.Name
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your idea is good, but the Linq-to-sql code is messing up in EF. the corrisponding function to DataLoadOptions should be .Include() .. but it doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Comment: FYI, the crazy error msg i get is:  The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType2`2[helpme.mvc.Models.Category,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`2[helpme.mvc.Models.SubCategory,System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[helpme.mvc.Models.SubSubCategory]]]]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[helpme.mvc.Models.Category]'.

Comment: @Niels: Ah, yeah for the second case you might not be able to use a strongly-typed model, because it involves custom anonymous types.

Comment: @Niels: Regarding the "doesn't seem to work for some reason," do you just mean it still yields empty collections, or does it generate some sort of exception?

Comment: model.SubCategories is populated when i insert a break point in the controller, but when i get to the view to seems to have lost it? it only displays my Category level and not SubCategory level even though i foreach them both.

Comment: Does var sc in item.SubCategories has any value?  Can you read the values of  item.SubCategories  in the view, try to read it from a watch and see?  It is clear that if item.SubCategories  is null it will never reach  @foreach (var ssc in sc.SubSubCategories) [ 
            /ssc.Name 
        } 
One morething you can do is try sc.Name and see if it contains a value for sc.Name.

Answer (score 0):

Execution of queries on views is not right. Better option would be to form you ViewModel than to pass it to view.

For turn on eager loading for multiple entities try to use [.Include()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx) passing there query path:

```
db.Category.Include("SubCategory.SubSubCategory").ToList();
```

Or if you are ising DbContext:

```
   db.Category.Include(s=>SubCategory.Select(ss=>ss.SubCategory).ToList();
```

MSDN documentation of .Include says:

> Paths are all-inclusive. For example, if an include call indicates
>   Include("Orders.OrderLines"), not only will OrderLines be included,
>   but also Orders